# How can I append a matrix to a matrix in python?

Tags: python, matrix, append

I was wondering how I can append a selected part of a matrix to a matrix in python?
The link below shows the excel file data that I am using and am trying to append with:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAkTn.png)

My current program is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
main=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/testfile/testing.csv', header=None)
main_transposed=main.T
#Next excel file
wave_file=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/testfile/nxt_Test.csv', header=None)
wave_transposed=wave_file.T
```

Thanks

Comment: Add some sample data, and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the best for matrix problems is the Numpy library, so convert your DataFrame to ndarray (simply) then use the bellow concept of collecting parts of the matrix:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b=np.array([[10,12,11],[100,5,79]])
b1_above_a=np.reshape(np.append(b[1,:],a),(4,3))
a_above_b1=np.reshape(np.append(a,b[1,:]),(4,3))
```

Now the b1_above_a is the second row of b put above matrix a, and the reverse with a_above_b1, that we put the whole matrix a above the second row of b.
Now keep in mind the output will be flattened so reshape it.

Comment: Hi @Hasanen A. Sahib. I just successfully did this thanks. sorry I was wondering when I'm using big data how I can identify what the newer matrixes dimensions will be without manually inputting or counting them? For the 1_above_a=np.reshape(np.append(b[1,:],a),(4,3)) code (4,3) part for example. cheers

Comment: Your welcome, and for not manually specifying the new shape you can only specify the columns numbers (which remain as it is when stacking rows), and due it is required to both have the same No. of columns we use `np.shape(a)[1]` or `np.shape(b)[1]` and for new rows let it -1 to default align, to be as:
`b1_above_a=np.reshape(np.append(b,a),(-1,np.shape(a)[1]))
a_above_b1=np.reshape(np.append(a,b[1,:]),(-1,np.shape(b)[1]))`